# jQuery click on modal not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing this mini chrome extension in which I insert a button(link) into a page and clicking on it(programatically) will bring the modal up. This works when I click it from the console even with the same jQuery command. But when I do it from the script file itself, it just reloads the current page because the link is obviously the current url of the page since the modal is supposed to be opened on top that page. Clicking with mouse manually works too. But I do not know why clicking the link from the file itself just reload the page without opening up the modal.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(res,sender,sender){
 var fileurl = chrome.extension.getURL("modal.js")

 var html = "<a href="#" data-modal="#modal2" class="modal__trigger">Modal </a>....the rest of html here';

 $('#rightCol').prepend(html);
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = fileurl;
 $("head").append(script);
 
 $('.modal__trigger')[0].click(); //this click reload the current page without opening up the modal
 
});
```

Comment: You need to fix your quotation marks -  `var html = '<a href="#" data-modal="#modal2" class="modal__trigger">Modal </a>....the rest of html here';`

Comment: Also the injected script takes some time to be processed, so maybe add a timeout before clicking or use `script.onload` or `dispatchEvent` instead of `click()`

Comment: @wOxxOm you're god damn right! I wait 2 secs with ```setTimeut``` function and now it is working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The injected script takes some time to be parsed and executed.

- add a timeout before clicking

  ```
  setTimeout(function() { $('.modal__trigger')[0].click() }, 1000);
  ```
- or use script.onload event

  ```
  script.onload = function() { $('.modal__trigger')[0].click() };
  $("head").append(script);
  ```